# Почему корабли плавают?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как говорят моряки, "корабли ходят, а плавает - ..." (ну, понятно, что))). А почему корабли именно ходят? И будет ли безграмотностью сказать, что они все-таки плавают?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Мы обсуждали похожий вопрос два года назад[link text][1]


  [1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/2292/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=2402#2402

Comment: Ларf, вопрос, может, и похожий, но ответ принципиально разный.
Ходят/плавают в круиз обычно сухопутные штатские, а в отношении судов и кораблей приходится считаться с мнением капитана и команды. 
(+)
А я еще удивился, что не помню "похожего" вопроса.

Comment: Я и говорю, что похожий, а не тот же. Даже некоторые Ваши замечания те же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утверждение, что корабли ходят, а не плавают, не носят обязательного характера.
Это такой "стебный" профессионализм. Вот, кстати, путать суда и корабли нежелательно. Корабли бывают парусные и военные, все остальное - суда. Эта терминология выходит за рамки чисто профессиональной.

Что же касается "ходить" - "плавать", то тут логично вспомнить правила использования т. н. глаголов движения.

Плавать - держаться на воде, плыть - передвигаться в выбранном направлении. 
Ходить же помимо того еще и систематически выполнять рейсы в каком-то направлении или определенного назначения. У "плавать" тоже есть подобное значение, но оно очень редкое и не "на слуху", значительно уступает вышеприведенному. Поэтому для определения регулярного движения логично использовать именно "ходить". 
В значении же разового перемещения "плыть" и "идти" в общем-то равноправны. Но упомянутый "стебный жаргон" требует и тут употребления идти (в прошедшем времени - шел, шли).
Для обозначения всякого другого движения у моряков есть ещё термины, например "дрейфовать" - в отношении не полностью управляемого или стихийного движения.

Comment: Точно! А то все подряд называют кораблями. Кстати, даже парусные не все, а с парусным вооружением фрегата.

Comment: Тут можно поспорить, не все так строго понимают...
Ну до этих ли тонкостей, когда у некоторых любая калоша - к**а**рабль.

Answer (score 5):

Судно идет, потому что это  управляемое движение в определенном направлении.Моряки используют традиционные морские термины чужих языков. Например, в английском языке "to go to sea" имеет значения "выйти в море" и "стать моряком", потому моряки и выходят в море, а не выплывают.

У корабля ХОД - движение в каком-то направлении (полный ход, задний ход) - это тоже термин. Кстати, у часов тоже ход, они тоже ходят, хотя ходит там только стрелка, и то по кругу.

В русском языке

ПЛЫТЬ 1. - передвигаться по поверхности воды. Лодка плывёт, человек плывёт, бумажный кораблик плывёт. Это бытовой глагол, не профессионализм.

Плыть 2. - ехать на судне или на ином плавучем средстве. Отдыхающие плывут на пароходе.

Плавать - уметь держаться на воде, не тонуть. Поэтому для моряков оскорбительно слышать, что они плавают,  корабль не просто держится на воде, он идёт к цели.

Но можно плавать - находиться в плавании: Он плавал матросом на пароходе. Это допустимо и верно. Плавать и плыть различаются по значению. Плыть-в каком-то направлении, плавать - по Ожегову - действие не в одном направлении, не в одно время, не за один приём. Так что плавать матросом можно, а плыть нельзя. Плыть можно пассажиром: "Однажды морем я плыла".

Answer (score 1):

Вообще по правилам русского языка судно "плавает".

Сугубо по профессиональному жаргону моряков - судно "ходит".

Но и по официальному морскому языку (не жаргонному) суда тоже "плавают". Отсюда официальные выражения и термины: "капитан дальнего плавания", "плавсостав" и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Как говорят моряки? Ходить или плавать? Принято считать, что настоящий моряк говорит только ХОДИТЬ, но на самом деле бывает по разному.

Смешит, когда человек, видавший море только в кино, начинает учить РЕАЛЬНОГО моряка, отдавшего морю пол жизни, как ему правильно говорить. Причем такой персонаж в своей правоте абсолютно уверен -  ведь это ему гугл сказал!

Впрочем, мне понятно почему так происходит.

Просто в литературе и на экранах специально злоупотребляют жаргоном что бы показать что вот это - моряк, в вот это - сухопутная крыса. Вот оттуда и пошли эти стереотипы. Но в реальной жизни, на судах, моряки разговаривают как привыкли и чаще всего вообще не используют жаргон. Причем, чем более опытный моряк, тем меньше он рисуется своей работой. Его море уже достало по самое немогу и лишний раз, используя жаргон, привлекать внимание к своей персоне, ему не надо. Зато сделавшие один - два рейса матрос жаргоном на берегу только и разговаривает - Надо же всем показать какой он "бывалый". Профессиональный жаргон не используют в быту, на то он и профессиональный!

Это только в кино и анекдотах моряк дома  говорит "компАс" вместо "кОмпас", "палуба" вместо "пол", "камбуз" вместо "кухня", "гальюн" вместо "туалет" и прочие морские термины применительно к туристическому компасу или частям собственной квартиры. На самом деле это признак околоморского ушлепства. Всему должно быть свое место и назначение.

Вот скажите мне кто на судне самый грамотный и бывалый моряк? Капитан, старший механик и старпом!

По должностным обязанностям им приходится каждый день писать х...ву кучу разных документов. Писать приходится на официальном, бюрократическом языке. Приходится постоянно общается с властями и официальными представителями всевозможных проверяющих организаций. Не так сказанное слово может иметь очень большие и неприятные последствия. Тут жаргону не место.

Это как блатная феня. Её можно рисанутся в компании гопников во дворе, но не на заседании суда.

Проще вообще его не употреблять. Вот и не употребляют. И это входит в привычку. 
Вот матросу на палубе пофиг как и что говорить, от его слов ничего не зависит. Так и набирают их частенько из бывших парикмахеров и таксистов на пару рейсов. Вот они то и являются наилучшими "носителями морских традиций", "блюстителями стародавних обычаев" и "хранителями морского сленга".

Вместо знаний и реального морского опыта в головах только микс из пары фильмов и нескольких прочитанных детских книжек про пиратов..

Comment: Вы интрересно рассказываете и правильные вещи говорите, но давайте и вы тогда ближе к теме и покорректнее. А то ведь и вас нетрудно обвинить в "околоязыковом ушлепстве". Мы же не разбираем  то как говорят моряки **дома**. А что касается гальюна и крмпАса, то не вижу ничего зазорного в том, что самый что ни на есть менсальватер иронически пошлет дома жену на камбуз или еще на какой клотик.

Comment: Вот вы лучше скажите, **10 узлов в час** - это что такое и сколько в километрах? Именно так как сказал, если ни слова не убирать.)))

Comment: @behemothus 10 узлов в час — это ускорение. Довольно малое: всего-то около 1,4 мм/с².

Comment: @.Ruslan Не подсказывайте

Answer (score 0):

Я скажу вам правильный ответ. Раньше под парусами плыли, а как приспособили винт к кораблю, с тех пор начали говорить "ходить", потому что винт крутиться, у него есть момент шага, оттуда и пошло это!

Answer (score 0):

Любопытно, что суда могут не только плавать, ходить, ездить (изредка), но еще и:
БЕГАТЬ (касп.) — ходить на лодке под парусами http://www.randewy.ru/sign/flagbuki.html .